# Unadjustable wheel alignment?

Tags: wheels, alignment

The guy at the just tire told me the alignment is not adjustable, I need new parts If i want to fix it, and also told me it won't effect the tire, is this true? 
One of my friends told me it will wear off the tires [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did the technician tell you what parts needed to be fixed/changed (ie: what is actually wrong)?

Comment: @paulster.      No, he didn't tell what part, he just said it is not worth it, and only took him 45 minutes to do the alignment, normally it should take longer,  right?      I took my car on the  highway and let go my steering wheel the car drift to the right side, I am so worried.

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at that the alignment is definitely **way** out - The factory specs for the 9th Gen civic say front camber should be 0°, the camber at the front is adjustable via the bolt where the strut attaches to the knuckle. If the alignment guy was saying he couldn't adjust that it may be as simple as the bolt being seized or it could be that something else in the suspension is bent.

This is likely the biggest cause of your handling issues - and the alignment guy was (if you'll excuse me being blunt) full of crap. Running circa 1.5° negative camber over spec is going to make a substantial difference to the inner tire wear on that left front. Not to mention the fact that the differential will make it handle like crap! (as you've already discovered)

The rear camber isn't adjustable from the factory on these and while the left rear is only *slightly* out of range (factory range is -0.8° to -1.5° IIRC) the relative difference between the two is quite large. I'd hazard a guess that the left rear has the "original" control arm on it - which gave -1.5° and the right has the later "C" spec one that Honda introduced to reduce rear tire wear. To be honest running a matched pair one way or the other is fine - the -1.5° ones give better rear handling and stability and the -0.8° ones give better tire wear so I'd go with whatever your priority is. Running a mismatch however is *not* going to help!

Comment: Thank you guys, after reading all this I think i should take it back to a different place to check if it is adjustable.

Comment: It's also possible that left front camber adjustment has reached it's limit. This can be caused by a variety of things. I think getting another set of eyes on it will add clarity to the situation.

Comment: @TimNevins Possible.. but if it's *that* far out while sat at it's limit of adjustment it would indicate something fairly substantially out of whack elsewhere. Agreed that a second pair of eyes on it would be the best plan